# Is there an option to keep the same color for nodes with the same label? Sankey plot in R

Tags: r, colors, sankey-diagram, googlevis

I'm creating Sankey plots with 4 years observations, each year I have the same variables (nodes with the same label as the year before9. I would like to have the same colour for each node with the same label. Is this possible?

I tried with some option but I did not find a solution.

```
options = list(sankey="{
    link: { colorMode: 'source'},

    node: {colorMode:'string',  colors: ['#1f78b4','#a6cee3', ]}}"), )
```

R code:

```
Sankey <- gvisSankey(SHIVALVCI_widefile_1016_sankey, from="Var1", to="Var2", weight="Freq",

options = list(sankey="{
    link: { colorMode: 'source'},

    node: {colorMode:'string',  colors: ['#1f78b4','#a6cee3', ]}}"), )
```

and the label's name:

```
"IK","No prest"))
SHIVALVCI_widefile_1016$M48 <- factor(SHIVALVCI_widefile_1016$M48,
    levels = c(1111,1112,1121,1122,1211,1212,1221,1222,2111,2112,2121,2122,2211,2212,2221,2222),
    labels = c("All prest","IV ALV SH","IV ALV IK","IV ALV","IV SH IK","IV SH",
    "IV IK","IV","ALV SH IK","ALV SH","ALV IK","ALV","SH IK","SH",
    "IK","No prest"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this relatively easily with `ggforce`. The following seems to do the trick with Titanic data. I modified the code slightly from the example in `?geom_parallel_sets` to add a `fill` aesthetic to `geom_parallel_sets_axes()` such that color maps to levels of the X axis variables (years in your case). Note that since the nodes don't repeat here (as you would have in different years), the colors are unique for each variable on the X axis.

```
library(ggforce)
?geom_parallel_sets


data <- reshape2::melt(Titanic)
data <- gather_set_data(data, 1:4)
ggplot(data, aes(x, id = id, split = y, value = value)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = Sex), alpha = 0.3, axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(aes(fill=y), axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = 'white')
```

[image: e]